# How do you properly nest multiple routes with react-router 5

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Basically I have an admin header that navigates to /admin. There I want to have a link to travel to /admin/render and display a component there. However, nothing displays at /admin/render. What am I missing?

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-nesting-forked-zxp7w?file=/index.js:0-1807

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React from "react";
import {
BrowserRouter as Router,
Switch,
Route,
Link,
useParams,
useRouteMatch
} from "react-router-dom";
import {
Grid,
AppBar,
Container,
IconButton,
List,
ListItem,
ListItemText,
Toolbar
} from "@material-ui/core";

ReactDOM.render(<NestingExample />, document.getElementById("root"));

export function NestingExample() {
return (
    <Router>
    <div>
        <Grid container>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
            <List>
            <ListItem component={Link} to="/admin">
                <ListItemText primary="Admin" />
            </ListItem>
            </List>
        </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <hr />

        <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
            <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/admin" component={AdminLanding} />
        </Switch>
    </div>
    </Router>
);
}

function Home() {
return (
    <div>
    <h2>Home</h2>
    </div>
);
}

function AdminLanding() {
let { path, url } = useRouteMatch();

return (
    <Grid container>
    <Link to={`${url}/rendering`}>Rendering with React</Link>

    <Switch>
        <Route exact path={path}>
        <h3>Please select a topic.</h3>
        </Route>
        <Route path={`${path}/:topicId`}>
        <Topic />
        </Route>
    </Switch>
    </Grid>
);
}

function Topic() {
let { topicId } = useParams();

return (
    <div>
    <h3>{topicId}</h3>
    </div>
);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

The root route rendering your admin landing page is only rendered when the path is exactly "/admin".

```
<Route exact path="/admin" component={AdminLanding} />
```

Sub-routes will be excluded and not matched by the nested `Switch` since `AdminLanding` is no longer rendered.

## Solution

Remove the `exact` prop so the nested `Switch` handles matching nested pages.

```
<Route path="/admin" component={AdminLanding} />
```

I suggest also inverting the order (*or listing more specific paths before less specific paths*) of the nested routes so they also don't need the `exact` prop.

```
<Switch>
  <Route path={`${path}/:topicId`}>
    <Topic />
  </Route>
  <Route path={path}>
    <h3>Please select a topic.</h3>
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

**Note:** It also seems that you really want the nested header to always be rendered since it will only render the `h3` when not matched by any other path. Maybe this is just a simplified code example though. If not then it should probably be pulled and rendered *before* the `Switch`.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks a lot.